# Retrieve SUM(count) by ENUM value

Tags: mysql, sql

This is an example of my table:

```
drug_id | route (enum) | count
------------------------------
1       | PO           | 2
1       | IV           | 4
1       | IV           | 6
2       | PO           | 1
2       | PO           | 5
2       | IV           | 2
```

This is how I need the information. Basically its `SUM(count)` but in a column for each "route":

```
drug_id | PO | IV 
-----------------
1       | 2  | 10
2       | 6  | 2
```

I assume I need a pivot, which I was trying to learn about, but I cannot for the life of me piece together a succinct query which will work.

I've tried things like:

```
SELECT drug_id, PO, IV 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT drug_id, SUM(count) as PO, '0' as IV FROM `core_reports_antiinfectives` WHERE route="PO"
        UNION
        SELECT drug_id, SUM(count) as IV, '0' as PO FROM `core_reports_antiinfectives` WHERE route="IV"
    ) aa
```

However this gives me `0` for ALL `IV` columns, and I'm not convinced that its appropriate anyway - it'll need to "group" by `drug_id` and put the columns together, which I am also stuck on.

Is there something I am missing? Or is there a better way to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT drug_id,
        SUM(case route when 'po' then `count` else 0 end) totalPO,
        SUM(case route when 'iv' then `count` else 0 end) totalIV
FROM core_reports_antiinfectives
GROUP BY drug_id
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25f2d/4)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT   drug_id,
         SUM(IF(route='PO',count,NULL)) AS PO,
         SUM(IF(route='IV',count,NULL)) AS IV
FROM     core_reports_antiinfectives
GROUP BY drug_id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/894146/1/0).