# group by all enum values without specifying enum values

Tags: mysql, sql, enums, case

Given an `ENUM` column with some values like `a, b, c`, I wish to query the table, `GROUP BY` the column such that a default number (0) is returned even if no rows are found.

I've seen answers that use `CASE column WHEN 'a' THEN count = 0` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12348380/1097483), but that requires me to specify all the ENUM values.

Is it possible to do so without specifying the column's ENUM values?

For example with the following data:

3 rows with 'a', 2 rows with 'b', 0 rows in 'c',

```
SELECT COUNT(*), enum FROM
`table`
GROUP BY enum
```

Will return results for 'a' and 'b', but not 'c'. How do I get it for all possible ENUM values?

Comment: Can you give same sample data? Are you trying to perform pivot operation?

Comment: I'm asking what I think is a general question, but I've updated the question with some sample data anyway.

Comment: do you have a table that has all enum values listed in?

Answer (score 0):

You need a control table .. then left join

```
create table enumtbl (
  enum varchar(10)); 

create table tbl (
  enum varchar(10));

insert into enumtbl values ('A');
insert into enumtbl values ('B');
insert into enumtbl values ('C');

insert into tbl values ('A');
insert into tbl values ('A');
insert into tbl values ('A');
insert into tbl values ('A');
insert into tbl values ('B');
insert into tbl values ('B');


select e.enum, coalesce(t.cnt,0) as cnt
from enumtbl e
left join (
    select enum, count(*) as cnt
    from tbl
    group by enum) t
  on e.enum = t.enum;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c69a/1)